# Hyperlink loop in VBA and if statement contains pattern

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating simple hyperlink for a range of values as they are in text in original template. The hyperlink part is not working and also wondering the foreach case. I want the original text also to be seen as a hyperlink value in the cell. How do you do this in VBA?

Also how do you do the if statement if you want put it as the if contains pattern like "http://"?

The following does not work and I get errors.

```
Sub Convert_To_Hyperlinks()

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set rng = Range("E5:E10")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each Cell In rng

            If Cell <> "" Then
                ws1.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws1.Cell, Address:=ws1.Cell.Value, ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=ws1.Cell
            End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: "does not work and I get errors" - please elaborate.

Comment: The current error is with "Method or data member not found" and the reference is for "Anchor:=ws1.Cell"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Like` operator:

```vb
Sub Convert_To_Hyperlinks()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, rng As Range, cell As Range

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws1.Range("E5:E10")

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value Like "http://*" Then
            ws1.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:=cell.Value, TextToDisplay:=cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```